# How can the 3D-tensor dimensions be shuffled in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm familiar with theano `dimshuffle` function that allows permutation of dimensions of a tensor. I'm looking for an equivalent function in tensorflow (currently using 0.8.0).

Given a three-dimensional tensor `x`, which is indexed as `x[a,b,c]`, I'd like to do something like `x.dimshuffle(1,0,2)` so that I can index as `[b,a,c]`.

Is it supported? If not, how can I achieve same result by using already implemented methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, I think that *tf.transpose()* does exactly what you need. Simply pass the desired permutation as list in the second argument of the function.
For details see:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#transpose